# Select output from Generate in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a component, which is added several times by a generate command:

```
Gen_RayMemory: for i in 0 to RayCount-1 generate
    Mem: RayMemory
    generic map(
        length_data => Data_length,
        length_ray => RayLength,
        direction => '1'
    )
    port map(
        clk => clk,
        i_start => i_user,
        i_data => i_data,
        i_store => Rays_save(i),
        i_invalid => Rays_invalid(i),

        r_rd => select_ray(i),
        r_data => data_out(i) --    <- Fix here (std_logic_vector)
    );
end generate Gen_RayMemory;
```

Lets have a look a the ports starting with r_ only. Always only one of the components is enable by the r_rd signal. The enabled component will put its data to r_data.

Is there a elegant way, to combine these outputs to a single data_out? They could be OR-ed or multiplexed by select_ray(i).

Comment: So you want a better solution then OR-ing the outputs together or multiplex them based on `select_ray`?

Comment: I could store them in an Array and write some logic to select them again (or merge them by OR). I am looking for a more direct (inline) way.

Comment: In a *synthesisable* design, you need either multiplexers or `OR` logic. In my opinion, anything that didn't simply show this logic in the code in a plain way would just make the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can describe it using a high-impedance output of your RAM. All RAMs, which are de-selected, output all 'Z' on the data signal. Only the selected RAM actually outputs the requested value. Then, the outputs of all RAMs can be connected together without creating a short-circuit. That means, all RAMs "write" to the same signal. Some tools can even synthesize it, by replacing the 3-state driver by appropriate logic gates of the target architecture if required (e.g. ISE 14.7).

Example design:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity RAM is
  generic (
    CONTENT : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));

  port (
    read_enable : in  std_logic;
    read_data   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end entity RAM;

architecture rtl of RAM is
begin
  read_data <= CONTENT when read_enable = '1' else (others => 'Z');
end architecture rtl;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity top is
  generic (
    N : positive);          -- number of RAMs

  port (
    read_enable : in  std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    read_data   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end entity top;

architecture rtl of top is

begin  -- architecture rtl

  gRAMs: for i in 0 to N-1 generate
    RAM_inst: entity work.RAM
      generic map (
        CONTENT => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, 8)))
      port map (
        read_enable => read_enable(i),
        read_data   => read_data);
  end generate gRAMs;

end architecture rtl;
```

If you simulate it using this testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top_tb is
end entity top_tb;

architecture sim of top_tb is
  constant N : positive := 4;
  signal read_enable : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal read_data   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin  -- architecture sim
  DUT: entity work.top
    generic map (
      N => N)
    port map (
      read_enable => read_enable,
      read_data   => read_data);

  Stimuli: process
  begin
    wait for 10 ns;
    for i in 0 to N-1 loop
      read_enable(i) <= '1';
      wait for 10 ns;
      read_enable(i) <= '0';
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture sim;
```

then you get the following result:

[image: simulation output]

Comment: "Some tools can even synthesize it": important point ;-)